# cURL PHP won't execute

Tags: php, curl

so I'm trying to get the following code to work, but for some reason, even though the url is valid and works if I visit it by pasting into a browser, the curl never executes correctly. I'm supposed to get a returned string, but when using this php curl script, I get nothing. Any ideas why?

```
<?php
    $username ='';
    if(isset($_POST['user'])){
        $username = $_POST['user'];
   }

   $query = 'whitelist add '.$username;

  $command=urlencode($query);

$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://IPHERE/console?command=whitelist+add+sad");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
echo curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: have you checked what `curl_error($ch)` gives you

Comment: `IPHERE` isn't a valid server hostname.

Comment: Oh, I get it, that's a placeholder for `IP goes here`.

Comment: My bad I had it all wrong

Comment: @PatrickEvans, echo curl_error($ch); prints out nothing.

Comment: check the headers the browser sends by viewing developer tools in a `!IE` browser, then imitate them in cURL. the website probably requires a specific user agent or else cookie jar

Comment: @Kyle, did you place that right after the curl_exec call? (just making sure), or have you looked at your log files to see if the script itself is erroring out, might get nothing if you do not have like display_errors on etc?

Comment: @PatrickEvans, my fault got this error: couldn't connect to host. May have something to do with what verbumSapienti said.

Comment: @Kyle possibly, but you wouldnt get a couldnt connect to host, the site would return an error page like a 404,500 etc error or some response notifying of an error. Is the ip you are using visible from your server?

Comment: @verbumSapienti, so far I have discovered this: GET
200
OK
text/plain. How would I implement that in php

Comment: @PatrickEvans, I don't see any reason it shouldn't be. www.example.com works find with my code. But I can access my ip from outside my network.

Comment: @Kyle, click on it then headers will be the first tab

Comment: @verbumSapienti Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:IP:PORT
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36

Comment: open a console to your server, and run a `ping iphere`, and/or a `curl urlhere` and see if you get a response from either one, if not then your server is not able to see the ip.

Comment: I can not open a shell from my webserver as I do not have root access.

Comment: this a shared host server?

Comment: @Kyle now mimic those in CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

Comment: Yes its a virtual host from FatCow. But after contacting them they did say curl php sessions/connections were supported.

Comment: @verbumSapienti How? I don't see any documentation for that on their website.

Comment: @Kyle, that does not mean their server can see the computer at the ip address. What is the ip address to? your home computer? Are you sure you are using a visible ip (not a local ip like 192.168.0.1,127.0.0.1 etc), for instance, goto http://onlinecurl.com/ and enter in the exact url you are using and see if it returns a response.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: close
Server: Bukkit Minecraft HTTPConsole 2.4.0
Content-Type: text/plain
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store

Comment: It says 404 even though it was able to determine that it was a bukkit minecraft server running the httpconsole plugin.

Comment: is there a port part on the ip? some hosts do not allow opening connections any port besides port 80, this is the only other thing i can think of that would cause the couldnt connect to host error.

Comment: There is a unique port of 1122. It is port forwarded on my LAN. I will contact fatcow for information.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, they don't support curl on any unique port. So I'm basically stuck :/